# The div with id 'intro' should be hidden but it shows. What has gone wrong?

Tags: css, css-position

The div with `id="intro"` is supposed to be hidden but it shows. The main `container`, which is div with `"id=myQuiz"`, has `width and height 650px` and `'overflow' set to 'hidden'`. Now, if the div with `"class=intro"` has `margin 660px from the left`, it should be hidden because it's margin is higher than the maximum width of the main container. My code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="myQuiz">

    <h1>Test your knowledge:<span>Saturn</span></h1>
    <div class="progress"></div>
    <div class="intro"></div>

    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>Click begin to test your knowledge of Saturn</p>
    <p class="btn">Begin</p>
    <div class="question"></div>
    <div class="results"></div>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

CSS code is as follows:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?                      family=Titillium+Web:900|Roboto:400,100);

   body { background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; }

   #myQuiz {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;
 width: 650px; height: 650px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 background: #000 url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
#myQuiz h2 { font-size: 3em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100;}
#myQuiz h3 { font-size: 2.4em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100;}
#myQuiz p { margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;}
#myQuiz .btn {
display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; background-color: #c04b01;
color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px 15px; border-radius: 6px;
}

#myQuiz .intro { position: absolute; top:225px; left: 660px; width: 550px;}
#myQuiz .intro p { margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px; }
```

Here is the link to my code on jsfiddle.net:

https://jsfiddle.net/h02y8usu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide the `<div class="intro">` by adding `display: none` property to `.intro`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. That didn't change anything.

Comment: When I tried editing your code snippet by adding a <p> tag to <div id="intro">, I see that your code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you please explain on how you are able to see that div? Also, by add above property, I mean having '#myQuiz .intro {display: none; }' which is working fine to hide that div.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the 'fiddle'? You can see the result. I did as you told me, but it did not change anything. Each and every word written inside the intro div shows in the browser window.

Comment: There is nothing written inside your <div class="intro"></div>. How can you see anything in the browser window? Please check your fiddle code again.

Comment: closing tag for that div is just after the opening tag. No other tag is there in between.

Comment: As a courtesy, please upvote and/or accept answer if anything helped.

Comment: I misplaced the closing tag. Your answer has solved the problem. I have accepted your answer.